# How to get the environment in the class other than Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to use the environment

Normally I can get the environemnt like this in Controller.

```
$this->container->get(‘kernel’)->getEnvironment();
```

However other than Controller, how can I make it??

My idea is like this below.

Making original class to get environment.

```
namespace Acme\TopBundle\MyServices;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MyFunc
{
    private $em;
    private $env;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em,$env)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->env = $env;
    }

    public function getEnv(){
        return $this->env;
    }
```

then register service in config.yml

```
services:
    myfunc:
        class:   Acme\TopBundle\MyServices\MyFunc
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager,"%kernel.environment%"]
```

then for example in admin class how can I get environment??

```
namespace Acme\AdminBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Places\AutocompleteType;
class PlaceCatAdmin extends Admin
{
   public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
   // I want to get environment here
```

Comment: Avoid general classes like MyFunc.  If PlaceCatAdmin really needs the env then define a PlaceCatAdmin service and inject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is already available in admin classes through the admin pool.

You can retrieve it like so:

```
$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.environment');
```

For reference:

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/Admin/AbstractAdmin.php

> ```
> /**
>  * @return Pool
>  */
> public function getConfigurationPool()
> {
>     return $this->configurationPool;
> }
> ```

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/Admin/Pool.php

> ```
>   /**
>      * @var ContainerInterface
>      */
>     protected $container;
> ```

Comment: This works well thanks!! in my case not controller but in AbstractAdmin so, configurationPool is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

To access your environment variable through services not a good idea, but there is if any requirement like that then you can achieve this by that way:

```
namespace Acme\TopBundle\MyServices;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MyFunc
{
    private $em;
    private $env;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em,$env)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->env = $env;
    }

    public function getEnv(){
        return $this->env;
    }
```

service configuration as it is.
then to the access this in you Admin controller do this :

```
namespace Acme\AdminBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Places\AutocompleteType;
class PlaceCatAdmin extends Admin
{
   public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
      $env = $this->container->get('myfunc')->getEnv();
```

if you will treat your ENV variable as Public then you can also access by this way

```
$env = $this->container->get('myfunc')->env;
```

Comment: Show this error and can't access container...  `Notice: Undefined property: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\PlaceCatAdmin::$container`

Comment: You need to extend base controller in parent or current class then you can access container inside class else you need to treat your class as service and from there you can pass service container inside your arguments.
`use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; 
class PlaceCatAdmin extends Controller`

or add this to you admin class

`use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; 
class Admin extends Controller`

Comment: Unless PlaceCatAdmin is a controller then the idea of having it extend the base controller class is not only terrible but it still does not solve the problem of injecting the container.  Try it.  I know it may seem like controllers somehow magically access the container but they don't.  The handleRequest code actually takes care of injecting the container as needed.